# Distance measuring with turtle Python

Tags: python, distribution, python-turtle

I have written a programme that creates a random walk using certain distribution. For example, if it is a Cauchy distribution, the program generates an adequate random number and appends it to the list. Then this list is used by the turtle as a list of steps in a random direction. Now I would like to measure the distance between the turtle in each step and point (0,0) where the random walk is starting and I can't seem to find a good solution for that. It cannot be done with turtle.distance() because I want to draw a graph of dependence this distance on step count. My first idea was to get coordinates of each point that my turtle stops and then try to calculate distance using the Pythagoras theorem, but I make mistakes somewhere along the road and can't acquire them. Could someone explain why, please? Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

```
cauchylist = []
for i in randomlist:
    cauchylist.append(0.15*math.tan(((i-0.5)*math.pi)) )
    
Franklin = turtle.Turtle()
u = input("Which walk to walk? C - Cauchy or G - Gauss.")
if u == "C":
    start()
    walk(Franklin, cauchylist)
    cv = turtle.getcanvas()
    cv.postscript(file="walk_cauchy.ps")
    
    Franklin.penup()
    Franklin.fd()
    Franklin.end_poly()

    coordinates = Franklin.get_poly()
    turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

The distance of the current position of the turtle to the origin is calculated by squaring the posi-values, adding them and getting the square root from that:

```
from turtle import *
from math import sqrt
from random import seed, choice

seed(42) # ensure same randoms for demonstation purposes

def calc_dist(t):
    return sqrt(sum(map(lambda x:x*x, t.pos())))

t = Turtle()

dists = []

for _ in range(20):
    t.forward(choice(range(100))-50)
    t.left(choice(range(360))-180)
    dists.append(calc_dist(t))

print(dists)
```

Output:

```
[31.0, 68.97157492789178, 87.25113481192517, 98.48389701852805, 134.17622966161073, 
 141.40760908816227, 138.90181656585844, 128.76423765225354, 113.79561063931857, 
 108.70118700467432, 66.53516784607132, 87.40888728250773, 113.65616399911761, 
 115.22672747425487, 122.12225694530929, 128.35176588895283, 157.57222689310848, 
 128.33399580245668, 129.3846600939952, 153.87822281203412]
```

Do the calculation `sqrt(sum(map(lambda x:x*x, t.pos())))` after each move of the turtle and store the result in a list.

[image: tutle seeded path]

Comment: Thank you, it almost works.However, I have one more question. I cannot use t.forward and t.left commands because I get an error "invalid command name . canvas turtle". I think it's because my turtle walk is defined by function looking like that:  ```def walk(turtle, steps):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in steps:
        kat = random.random() * 360
        turtle.setheading(kat)
        turtle.forward(math.fabs(i))
        bounds(turtle) ```. However, if I don't use it as on the example You gave, I create list full of only last distance value.  Can anything be done about that?

Comment: @edva Then edit your random walk function and add each intermediate steps to a list to be returned from the walk function`?

Answer (score 0):

`get_poly()` will return a tuple of tuples.
Example:

```
coordinates = turtle.get_poly()
```

```
coordinates = ((0.00,0.00), (100.00,0.00), (128.19,10.26), (136.87,59.50))
```

You can easily acess each tuple with a for loop

```
for c in coordinates:
    print(c)
```

Output:

```
(0.00,0.00)
(100.00,0.00)
(128.19,10.26)
(136.87,59.50)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to measure the distance between the turtle in each step
> and point (0,0) where the random walk is starting and I can't seem to
> find a good solution for that. It cannot be done with
> turtle.distance()

This premise doesn't hold.  We can do `turtle.distance(0, 0)` which doesn't affect the turtle's state but gives us the distance to the origin.  To demonstrate, my rework of @PatrickArtner's example using `distance()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import seed, randint

seed(42)  # repeatable randomness for demonstration purposes

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

distances = []

for _ in range(20):
    turtle.forward(randint(-50, 50))
    turtle.left(randint(-180, 180))
    distances.append(turtle.distance(0, 0))

print(distances)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Console Output

```
> python3 test.py
[31.0, 68.97157492789178, 87.25113481192517, 98.48389701852807, 134.17622966161073,
 141.40760908816227, 138.90181656585844, 128.7642376522535, 113.79561063931855,
 108.70118700467431, 66.5351678460713, 87.4088872825077, 113.65616399911758,
 115.22672747425486, 122.12225694530927, 128.35176588895283, 157.57222689310848,
 128.33399580245668, 129.3846600939952, 153.87822281203412]
>
```

> I cannot use t.forward and t.left commands because I get an error
> "invalid command name . canvas turtle". I think it's because my turtle
> walk is defined by function looking like that:

```
def walk(turtle, steps):
     x = 0
     y = 0
     for i in steps:
         kat = random.random() * 360
         turtle.setheading(kat)
         turtle.forward(math.fabs(i))
         bounds(turtle)
```

> However, if I don't use it as on the example You gave, I create list
> full of only last distance value. Can anything be done about that?

We'd need to see more code to address this issue, e.g. the definition of `bounds()` and so forth.